# End of a proof of Borel-Lebesgue's theorem

Tags: general-topology

> If a compact $K$ of $\mathbb R$ is covered by a countable family of open sets, then a finite covering can be extracted.

Let's $(U_n)$ be a covering of $K$ formed of open sets and for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $V_n=\bigcup_{k=0}^n U_k$. Thus $(V_n)$ is a covering of $K$ and an increasing family of open sets.

**Lemma.** We can extract from $(V_n)$ a finite covering of $K$.

Otherwise, none of the $V_n$ would cover $K$ and we could always find $x_n\in V_n\setminus K$. But then worth extracting a convergent sequence, $x=\lim_n x_n\in K$ and from a certain rank $m\in\mathbb N$ we have $x\in V_m$… and I find no contradiction.

Comment: a) You seem to treat only *countably* infinite coverings. b) Why is the claimed property not your definition of *compact*?

Comment: a) I edited the post to add this clarification, thank you. b) Well, the definition of compact that I have been taught is "set where the BW theorem is true" (or "closed-bounded" in finite dimension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have our increasing open cover $(V_n)_n$ and $x_n \in K \setminus V_n$ for all $n$. We have $x \in K$ and a *subsequence* $(x_{n_k})_k$ that converges to $x$ as $k$ tends to infinity. As all $x_{n_k}$ are in $K$ so is $K$ and $x$ is covered by some $V_m$. As $V_m$ is open and we have convergence,

$$\exists K: \forall k \ge K: x_{n_k} \in V_m$$

and we can pick $k$ so that we have $m < n_k$ *and* $k \ge K$ and then for such $k$ we have $x_{n_k} \in V_m$ (as $k \ge K$) and also $x_{n_k} \in V_{n_k}^\complement \subseteq V_m^\complement$ (from the increasingness) which is the required contradiction.